# user profile and file upload

Tags: php, sql

I just created an profile site, that lets every registred user enter their own profile. At the time it shows email and username.

I also created an file uploader that saves filename in a SQL table and saves the file to a folder, there is also a file list so you can see every file that has been uploaded and the option to download it down again.

Now I want to connect this two thing  in some way, so when you login to your userprofile, you will be able to upload a file to the folder and display them directly in your profile. But of course the only ones you uploaded, not from every user.

I bet there is a method to do this, but since I'm a newbe I really dont know how to begin. So if someone has some tips, or maybe a method that's somewhere on the internet I'll be a happy noob :)

thanks

Comment: You need auth your user, when check user was auth, and show him the upload form. when user upload file, you need check user was auth, file size, file ext (beware *.php or any server-side executed files), and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in sql table for files add field of user id. Each time that users upload they files, they id will be stored in this table to. When User login You should select only files with this user id

Comment: I think Im on something here :)

I added file_name to my user table, so now every time I save a file the filename stores id the users table.

Could i use and if-else query to show only the files that been uploaded by a certain user ?

Comment: For certain user u should use something like this:  SELECT file_name FROM files WHERE user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']   It will select all files for Your user. (all field was named for example)

Comment: I tried this query and it almost work. When i changed the  user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] to  user_id = 'testid' It shows All the files from that ID, but when i Use the $_session[user_id] I get the error message 
"
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 "
Should i Instance the $session in some way ? so It know that i should get the information for the loaded user ?

Comment: If You have $_SESSION['user_id']  (after user login put his id into session). For query syntax You should use:  "SELECT file_name FROM files WHERE user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']" with this quotes and other way: 'SELECT file_name FROM files WHERE user_id =' .$_SESSION['user_id']

Comment: Hmm, cant get it right =/

I have another error now.

This is my query

$files = mysql_query("SELECT `file_name` FROM users WHERE `user_name` = {$_SESSION['username']} ") or die(mysql_error()); 

And the error message is now

Unknown column 'test1' in 'where clause'

Could it be that its reading the info inside the colum, as a column ?

Comment: Had forgot the ' ' . Working now :=)

This it the final querry

  $files = mysql_query("SELECT `file_name` FROM users WHERE  `user_name` = '{$_SESSION['username']}' ") or die(mysql_error()); 
 ?>

Answer (score 1):

Make a field user_id in your sql table.

Store user_id of loggedin user from session or whatever you using to login.

After that select all fields of file with loggedin userid to display in profile.

Answer (score 1):

Organize your file system like:

```
uploads/
  files/
    %user_name% or %user_id% (some unique identifier linked to the current user)/
```

This way you will always be able to show files only uploaded by that user.